# Parse a XML with attributes and attr values in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have a situation to parse an XML which is having much data in attributes and levels to access the data inside the XML hierarchy.

Confused about which parser to be used for this to be a effective approach for parsing. Parsing the XML and how to access the attributes & its value.

I was preferring DOM parser and trying to parse it but it was a little complex as i needed to get a tag -> then an attribute -> then attr value and on that condition need to get another tag access.

```
 <testCodeIdentifier classCode="ROL" >
                <realmCode code="QD" />
                <id assigningAuthorityName="PRMKEY" extension="SJC16494"  />
                <statusCode code="active" /> 
                <playingTestCodeDetails classCode="ENT" determinerCode="INSTANCE" >
                  <realmCode code="QD" />
                  <id assigningAuthorityName="PRMORDCODE" extension="16494"  />
                  <id assigningAuthorityName="TESTNUMINBOOK" extension="16494"  />
                  <code code="16494" codeSystemName="QTIM" displayName="SureSwab Candidiasis" /> 
              <name  use=""></name>
                  <asSeeAlsoCode classCode="ROL" > 
                    <realmCode code="QD" />
                    <code code="7600" displayName="Sample See Also Name" ></code>
                  </asSeeAlsoCode>    
                  <asSeeAlsoCode classCode="ROL" >
                <realmCode code="QD" />
                <code code="6496" displayName="Sample See Also Name" ></code>
                  </asSeeAlsoCode>
                </playingTestCodeDetails>
    </testCodeIdentifier>
```

Above is the sample XML in which all attributes are present as data i need to  traverse them... JAXB..how can we use it????

Comment: can you provide a quick example?

Comment: Added a sample XML and attributes needs to accessed; i am currently using DOM parser but it is somewat confusing to use it.

Comment: it is depend on your requirement if you want whole data at a time them better go for DOM but problem of DOM is it take huge memory for large XML file and if you want parse data in section wise then go with SAX parser both are efficient but DOM is more easier then SAX

Comment: XPath is often the simplest way to extract what you want. Problem is, you haven't stated what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF the size of the XML file isn't going to be *huge*, you can look at following options:

1. [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) (If you have a schema definition, it will generate the objects and auto populate for you).
2. [JiBX](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/) (Another good alternative. You can define custom mapping of XML attributes to Java Objects)
3. [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) (Also allows you to map XML attributes to Java Objects).

Comment: JAXB (JSR-222) can generate an object model from an XML schema, and like JiBX and XStream you can also start from objects and apply annotations to control how the classes are mapped to XML.

Comment: JAXB is that a specific jar; where can i download that from?? Any inputs how to use it??

Comment: @GOK - JAXB is actually a spec (JSR-222) with multiple implementations.  An implementation is available in Java SE 6.  I'm the EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) lead, and our impl is available at: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/ Other implementations include Metro and JaxMe.

Answer (score 0):

The approach depends on your needs. If you are going to use most of the values in complex business operations. Probably loading the XML with XStream or other binding framework is the way to go.
Now if you are only interested on a couple of values, and you are expecting to process large XMLs (or a lot of small ones). Probably Sax parsing might be a better fit.

Here is an example.

```
final SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
final SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

final DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName,
             final Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

         System.out.println("Start Element :" + qName);

         if ("realmCode".equals(qName)) {
             System.out.println(attributes.getValue("code"));
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName)
                    throws SAXException {
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char ch[], final int start, final int length) throws SAXException {
    }

  };


  saxParser.parse(myInputStreamOrFile, handler);
```